# How to close a custom drop down menu when user clicks somewhere else on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a custom select menu that needs to have the menu options close when ever a user clicks somewhere else on the document.  However it's not doing this and I'm confused.  Likewise, a user can have multiple drop down menus open at the same time, this is also something that's not desired.  Can someone explain how I need to fix this?

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="select">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="option-menu">
            <div class="option">Hello</div>
            <div class="option">Goodbye</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="option-menu">
            <div class="option">A</div>
            <div class="option">B</div>
            <div class="option">C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $(".select");
    $(select).on("click", function(){
        select = $(this);
        $(this).find(".option-menu").each(function(){
            $(this).toggle();
        })

        $(".option").on("click", function(){
            $(select).children("p").remove();
            var value = $(this).text();
            $(select).prepend("<p>" +value +"<p>");
        })
    })
})
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
#main{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 15%;
}
.select{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.arrow{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    height: 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.option-menu{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 240px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.option{
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.active{
    background-color: blue;
}
.select p{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Here also is my pen.

http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/LIKsJ

Comment: You notice you didn't close quotes in your example?

Comment: What quotes aren't closed?  Because each quote I see is closed.

Comment: Cause i fixed it when edit the OP :) See my edit and you understand.

Comment: Ah, I see it now.  That if statement actually doesn't work.  I need to remove it from the question.  Nice catch though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some class to operate with, like `current` and then just hide current elem

```
$(this).find(".option-menu").each(function(){
  $('.current').hide();
  if ($(this).hasClass('current')){
     $(this).removeClass('current');
  }else{     
     $(this).show().addClass('current'); 
  } 
})
```

And for hiding your menu when clicking not on it

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
   if ( $(e.target).closest('.select').length === 0 ) {
      $('.current').hide().removeClass('current');
   }
})
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IKJbk)

Answer (score 2):

Stop the propagation of the event in the drop down:

```
$('.option-menu').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    $(".option-menu").hide();
});
```

You tell the option-menu to close when you click on the body, but since the event propagation it stopped, the click event will never reach the body, when you click inside the option-menu.

PS: Your codepen example doesn't work for me, so I can't provide a working example.

Answer (score 2):

```
In CoffeeScript, do something like this:

$('.more-btn').on 'click', (e) ->
  if $('.card-content.more').hasClass('show-more-menu')
    $('.card-content.more').removeClass('show-more-menu')

  $(e.target).closest('.card-content.more').addClass('show-more-menu')

$(document).on 'click', ->
  $(".card-content.more").removeClass('show-more-menu')

$('.card-content.more').on 'click', (e) ->
  e.stopPropagation()
```